# Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using Google's free Distance Matrix API to calculate the miles between two addresses. I pass in from and to addresses and it returns the miles but throws an error saying parameter count exception error.

```
function calculateMiles(from, to) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + from + "&destinations=" + to + "&mode=driving&sensor=false&units=imperial"
            }).done(function(response) {
                var miles;
                $.each(response.rows, function() {
                    $.each(this.elements, function() {
                        miles = this.distance.text;
                        return false;
                    });
                    return false;
                });  
                $('#miles').val(miles);
            }).fail(function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
```

Comment: What are the values of `from` and `to`?

Comment: var from = "2700+bay+area+blvd+houtson+texas";
var to = "300+cyberonics+blvd+houston+texas";

Comment: it returns the result but on the page, i get Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch error. The click event does not work after I get this error.

Comment: At what line do you get the error? This works when I paste the entire code in the console on the StackOverflow site.